# terminal service remoteapp disappears when opening file

Tags: windows, terminal-server, remoteapp

Every domain user has a mapped drive with a label of N:  This is where the software and data is kept.  For now, a user must run an installer on their local machine and adjust the "target" and "start in" parameters to point to the network share (N:).

Example:  Software installed locally has the following Shortcut parameters:

Target: N:\QA\qaedit.exe

Start in: N:\QA_Data\Current

I am trying to deploy this software using our remoteApp server (located on a separate server than where the application resides).  I create a remoteApp with a location of N:\QA\qaedit.exe.  After I deploy it, it installs and runs fine.  However, when I try to OPEN a file within this app, the app just disappears.  I am trying to have it open to N:\QA_Data\Current. After installing this remoteApp, I tried to edit the shortcut parameters to point to the desired directory but it yields the same results.  Is there additional options I must configure?  Is there a command-line parameter that I may be missing?  All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "just disappears"? We really don't have anything to go on here. Have you checked the event log? Can you tell if the program is crashing?

Comment: I will double check the event log but the screen literally disappears as if I closed the application\

Comment: Being my first time working with terminal services, where would be the best place to look in event viewer for such events to see what may be happening?

Comment: Under the Application logs. Keep in mind there's nothing terribly special about remoteApp. You're still logging in to a server and running an app. Try running the program while RDPed in to the server instead and see if an error message pops up, or if the app simply crashes to the desktop. If it works fine, check the application logs and see if there's an error that can help you hunt down the problem.

Comment: After RDPing into the server and running the application, it works as expected.  I checked the application logs, and there is nothing being logged when the window "disappears" or "crashes".  I forgot to mention that at times I am able to open a file without issue.  However, if I test it 2 minutes later, clicking open will crash the application. This is very odd.

Comment: After further digging around, I found he following event 9003: The Desktop Window Manager was unable to start because a composited theme is not in use

Comment: I now notice a user profile event:

Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards.  

 DETAIL - 
 1 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-2567557857-241090614-473706881-3204:
Process 720 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2567557857-241090614-473706881-3204\Printers\DevModePerUser